# Do I need to use $(document).ready() when using $(document.createElement())?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, createelement

I want to create a set of elements to add to a HTML document using JQuery's `$(document.createElement())`. I know `$(document).ready()` is required before starting using document elements.

However, is it necessary to use `$(document).ready()` in order to create elements with `$(document.createElement())`? In other word, can I use `$(document.createElement())` in a document before it is ready?

Comment: This would be fairly simply for you to test yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie to javascript. How would I be sure I would be testing this properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a new  node at any time. But if you're going to be inserting it into the page's DOM, then you'll have to use .ready(), otherwise there's no guarantee that the spot you're trying to insert into exists yet.

Answer (score 2):

I create new nodes before ready when I preload my images in the head... so It's not totally essential as a general rule or anything.